# PhoneGap - Best way to play sound files

Tags: android, cordova

I am using PhoneGap (Cordova) and trying to play a single sound file and then properly release the resource when I navigate to a different page.

This is how I am playing the sound file

```
var my_media = null;

 function playAudio(src) {
        // Create Media object from src
        if(my_media == null){
            my_media = new Media(src, onSoundSuccess, onSoundError);
        }

        // Play audio
        my_media.play();
    }

    // Audio - onSuccess Callback
    //
    function onSoundSuccess() {
        console.log("Audio played");
    }

    // Audio - onError Callback 
    //
    function onSoundError(error) {
        console.log('sound error - code: '    + error.code);
        console.log('sound error - message: ' + error.message);
        if(my_media != null){
            my_media.release();
        }
    }
```

And this is the code I call when I navigate away from the page

```
if(my_media != null){
        my_media.release();
    }
```

However I always get the following error in the logcat after leaving the page and releasing the resource

```
10-09 12:09:07.843: D/MediaPlayer(32246): release() in
10-09 12:09:07.853: D/MediaPlayer(32246): release() out
10-09 12:09:07.853: V/MediaRecorderJNI(32246): native_reset
10-09 12:09:07.853: V/MediaRecorderJNI(32246): getMediaRecorder E
10-09 12:09:07.853: V/MediaRecorderJNI(32246): process_media_recorder_call
10-09 12:09:07.853: V/MediaRecorderJNI(32246): release
10-09 12:09:07.863: V/MediaRecorderJNI(32246): setMediaRecorder E: mr = null
10-09 12:09:07.863: V/MediaRecorderJNI(32246): setMediaRecorder X
10-09 12:09:07.903: D/CordovaWebView(32246): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/page.html)
10-09 12:09:07.903: D/CordovaWebView(32246): >>> loadUrlNow()

10-09 12:09:07.903: W/System.err(32246): java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
10-09 12:09:07.903: W/System.err(32246):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.accept(Native Method)
10-09 12:09:07.903: W/System.err(32246):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.accept(BlockGuard.java:262)
10-09 12:09:07.903: W/System.err(32246):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:95)
10-09 12:09:07.903: W/System.err(32246):    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:264)
10-09 12:09:07.903: W/System.err(32246):    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:150)
10-09 12:09:07.903: W/System.err(32246):    at org.apache.cordova.CallbackServer.run(CallbackServer.java:195)
10-09 12:09:07.903: W/System.err(32246):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong but I am not sure what it could be.

I tried just not releasing the media object which makes the error go away, however after some time using the app I get an error because of the resources being piled up and not being released properly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the code at the url below: 
https://gist.github.com/2380994 
ie put mp3 into www and load '/android_asset/www/test.mp3' on android. 
It works here.

Comment: while trying the suggested code with my audio file, I am getting error message unknown stream type.